# Execute parent class method without calling super()

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

We have the following class structure:

```
class NamePrinter():
    def phone():
        print(self.name)

    def email():
        print(self.name)


class PhoneCaller(NamePrinter):
    def __init__(self, name, number, mail):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.mail = mail

    def phone(self):
        # here, NamePrinter.phone() should be executed
        compose_number(self.number)

    def email(self):
        # here, NamePrinter.email() should be executed
        compose_mail(self.mail)
```

I want `NamePrinter.phone()` to be executed when `PhoneCaller.phone()` is called, without having to mention `super.phone()` in PhoneCaller.

The idea is that the only modification to be applied to PhoneCaller in order for it to execute NamePrinter's behaviour when PhoneCaller.phone is executed, is that PhoneCaller inherits from parent, and nothing more. In particular, no need to modify any individual PhoneCaller method.

To put it simpler:

- PhoneCaller inherits from NamePrinter => name is printed before composing number
- PhoneCaller doesn't inherit from NamePrinter => name is not printed
- No need to mess around into PhoneCaller.phone

Is this possible?

Comment: In `class NamePrinter` rename to `def _phone(self):`, in `def phone(self):` do `self._phone()`.

Comment: @stovfl in what way is it different from calling super()?

Comment: The first two bullet points seem to imply you might modify `PhoneCaller`'s base class. If that's the case, why not just define two classes to begin with, and define the one that is a child of `NamePrinter` properly? This seems like a giant XY problem.

Comment: See `import this`: "Explicit is better than implicit."

Comment: @chepner the real-world scenario is we have dozens of different child classes and we want a simple switch to trigger an alternative behavior, depending on this switch being on or off

Comment: Sounds like you are grossly misusing inheritance, then.

Comment: @chepner possibly. We are more attached to the actual use case than to using inheritance for the sake of it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible at least with metaclass:

```
def new_attr(attr_name, attr):
    name_printer_attr = getattr(NamePrinter, attr_name)

    def _new_attr(self, *args, **kwargs):
        name_printer_attr(self)
        return attr(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return _new_attr


class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if name == 'NamePrinter':
            cls.attrs = attrs
        else:
            for attr_name, attr in attrs.items():
                if callable(attr) and attr_name in cls.attrs:
                    attrs[attr_name] = new_attr(attr_name, attr)
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class NamePrinter(metaclass=Meta):
    def phone(self):
        print('NamePrinter phone')


class PhoneCaller1:
    def phone(self):
        print('PhoneCaller1 phone')


class PhoneCaller2(NamePrinter):
    def phone(self):
        print('PhoneCaller2 phone')


p1 = PhoneCaller1()
p1.phone()  # will print only "PhoneCaller1 phone"
p2 = PhoneCaller2()
p2.phone()  # will print "NamePrinter phone" and "PhoneCaller2 phone" on next line
```

Comment: Looks great. Kind of a shame on Python’s side to have to go through these shenanigans to implement what is quite a simple concept after all... Great answer though.

Comment: @Jivan Rewriting existing code at run-time is hardly "simple".

Comment: @chepner I’d love to hear a better solution for this use-case, if you have one I’m all open

Comment: I would drop the restriction that I can't modify `PhoneCaller`.

Answer (score 1):

And there is another solution with decorator. It saves you from misusing inheritance and is more clear and flexible (IMHO):

```
def new_attr(attr_name, attr, from_cls):
    from_cls_attr = getattr(from_cls, attr_name)

    def _new_attr(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from_cls_attr(self)
        return attr(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return _new_attr


def use_methods(from_cls):
    dir_from_cls = dir(from_cls)
    def modify(cls):
        for attr_name in dir(cls):
            if not attr_name.startswith('__') and attr_name in dir_from_cls:
                attr = getattr(cls, attr_name)
                if callable(attr):
                    setattr(cls, attr_name, new_attr(attr_name, attr, from_cls))
        return cls
    return modify


class NamePrinter:
    def phone(self):
        print('NamePrinter phone')


class PhoneCaller1:
    def phone(self):
        print('PhoneCaller1 phone')


@use_methods(NamePrinter)
class PhoneCaller2:
    def phone(self):
        print('PhoneCaller2 phone')


p1 = PhoneCaller1()
p1.phone()
p2 = PhoneCaller2()
p2.phone()
```